# Better way to handle the Global Account Details and Master Information in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC5 application, I have account based login system. when the user login in to there accounts we have to query the database for master information and store it somewhere in application. Because we need to use that in every pages. So initially i have followed **Session** to store the information. But i want to know, **Is there any better option to handle the data**.

For more clear
I want to handle the Master data like default Asp.Net User Identity, In that we use

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

**For eg:**
  Now im using like this

**Class File**

```
public class MyClassProperty
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
 List<MyClassProperty> obj = context.MyMaster.Tolist();
 Session["MyClassProperty"]=obj;
```

**Views**

```
@{var obj =(List<MyClassProperty>)Session["MyClassProperty"];}
@obj.Id
@obj.Value
```

But i want to access data like this in view or other controllers

```
@MyClassName.MyClassProperty.Id
```

Can any one suggest me to solve this.

if the question is not clear please comment.

Comment: Attached the "information" class to a model class and pass that to your view accordingly (and possibly other controllers, though they should be able to get it from the session/cache easily enough).

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not using asp.net identity?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a rather extensive bit of research on various ways to handle this type of information, and my takeaway was that persisting the data in a database, having a model to type to it and storing "live" values in the session is probably the most flexible way to handle it without having to write your own logic for caching it.  The only thing to be particularly careful of, I think, is to try to keep the size/footprint of this data small, as the session can chew up memory easily.

Concerning the builtin profile/identity management, yes, you can use that and that alone to handle much of this, but I've found that it's not entirely flexible (or if it is, it's not easily flexible) and that much of the data I would track is more specific to the domain rather than the MVC/presentation layer itself, so by using a database to store all of the "extra" info, we get away from being stuck to MVC for it and have greater flexibility.

As for exposing this information to your view, you should be attaching it to a viewmodel class of some sort.  Here's the basic idea:

```
// the core model for the user info
public class UserProfile {
    public int SomeValue {get;set;}
}

// a viewmodel for some specific view:
public class MyViewModel : DomainObject {
    public UserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}
}

// from your controller:
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    var model = repository.GetMyViewModel();
    model.UserProfile = Session["UserProfile"] as UserProfile;
    return View(model);
}
```

(ok, so the repository should probably be responsible for handling the assignment of the UserProfile information as well as the core view's model, but this makes for easy demonstration).

```
// then in your view:
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserProfile.SomeValue)
```

Comment: I think that anyone who is considering this answer seriously should first read [Think twice about using session state](http://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). It *specifically* states that profile information should not be in session and gives several reasons why this isn't a good approach, especially for modern AJAX applications. Whatever pains you must go through to get the ASP.NET Identity profile functionality to work are definitely worth the more scalable & responsive result.